# Redirect OWASP ZAP IP:Port to localhost like in Burp

Tags: burp-suite, zap

I want to intercept an application. It connects to an IP and port. I have to connect to localhost:443 to make it work (there's a gateway that routes depending on the port).

In Burp I was able to set an invisible proxy on the local interface (not 127.0.0.1, 192.168.x.x) listening on port 443 and redirecting it to 127.0.0.1:443.
Interception worked. Since Burp does not support Websocket testing I want to use OWASP ZAP, because it has a native support for Websockets and fuzzing and stuff.

Is there a way in OWASP ZAP to redirect the traffic the same way like I did in Burp? Edits in the hostfile won't work since I can't map 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1.

//short: I want the listener from the following picture (Burp) in ZAP.

[image: Image of Burp redirection]

Answer (score 1):

in the menu bar go to `Tools -> Options -> local Proxies`

This [blog post](https://chrisdecairos.ca/intercepting-traffic-with-zaproxy/) contains some infomration on how to intercept traffic with OWASP ZAP

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can redirect traffic to ZAP using IP tables, eg:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.14:8443 
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.14:8080
```

For more details see https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsSniTerminatorSniTerminator

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited to Windows but thank you for your reply.